# how to create a SUM that says "When I put data in O11, FREEZE the figure in K11 - newest Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

basically my SUM in days remaining (K11) is if “date invoice sent out column is empty - show blank, also invoice due date - =TODAY (todays date)

But obviously the days remaining column will keep changing as the B2 column will keep updating with the new date. So I want a sum that basically says

“When I put data in O11, FREEZE K11. So basically once the invoice is paid the days remaining will freeze so I can reference back and see how long it took them to pay but it won’t keep going down once they’ve actually paid it.

Comment: This will cause a circular reference, which with formulas is problematic.  You will want vba in a Worksheet_Change Event.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm unsure what a VBA is i'm not that advanced at excel.. trying but not quite! Could you explain please

Comment: VBA is Visual Basic for Applications.  It's a programming language that lets users write their own programs to do things with cell contents that can't be done via native functions.  It gives you access to details and functions that aren't available on the spreadsheet, and lets you create processes rather than just a result.

Answer (score 0):

On the formula part.. + condition as it is.. , I have no idea.

But, if you don't mind typing an extra bit, then you can use cell O11 as helper cell.

The idea is.. instead of just filling up "Paid" or K11. You do that + insert today's date (manually) in O11. For this to work you'll need to change the formula in K11 to :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E11),"",IF(ISBLANK(D11),E11-O11,E11-$B$2))
```

Answer (score 0):

=IF(ISBLANK(E11),"",IF(ISBLANK(O11),E11-$B$2,E11-O11))

i posted the above SUM and it appears to work - when the invoice due date is filled out the days remaining column continues to count down. when data is entered into invoice paid the days remaining column freezes. Just what i wanted - only issue i have is when no data is entered - the cell shows VALUE!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any native function that can achieve what you're asking for. 
 Likely, there's some way to achieve it through VBA coding but inferring from the contents of the spreadsheet, this is being used in a corporate setting -- where security policies typically don't play nice when it comes to .xlsm files.

What I would suggest instead is to derive that same data value via a `Paid` date value.  However, I don't believe you need to add on another data entry step to your current form procedure.  Chances are, someone in your organization (likely in AR) is already entering that data somewhere, and depending on your network security policies you might be able to directly reference that data over your local intranet.  Your best bet is to see if you can link your sheet to an external data connection and cross-reference by `Invoice Number` for `Check Date`, then derive the difference between that and `Due Date`; depending on your intended usage and what degree of precision or accuracy you *actually* require, I would assume check dates are sufficient in common settings (just keep in mind it wouldn't reflect real-world practices such as post-dated checks, etc).

If your accounting utilizes software such as QuickBooks rather than spreadsheets, it may be more complicated to create the connection and you may want to consult with someone with appropriate knowledge and seniority to help accomplish a live sync.  Optionally in that scenario, you can simply ask your accounting to setup a recurring report export via, e.g., .csv format to a predetermined network directory (which I believe can also be automated), to which you can directly reference via formula.

Hope that helps, and feel free to let me know if you need any more in-depth help on the subject.